# Efficiently get positions of Query results

Tags: dataset, index, query

I have some very large Datasets. Is there any efficient method of getting the positions of results found in a `Query`? That is, without using `Normal` and `Position` again on the results after the query returns.

**Here’s an example**

When querying 2D datasets (lists of assns) it can be (like with Pandas) easier and faster to only deal with vectors of indices when applying conditions, not the results themselves:

```
d = ExampleData[{"Dataset","Titanic"}]
cases = d @ Query[Select[#sex=="male" && #class=="1st" && #age>70 &]]
Position[Normal[d], #]& /@ Normal[cases] (* doing this is silly *)
```

I don’t want to call `Normal` and `Position` after the fact (which might be prohibitively slow) but rather, I'm looking for `Query` to return only the indices of the results it finds.

`Query` acts like Cases, but there's no analog for `Position`, e.g. something like `QueryIndexed` or `QueryPosition` that gives the lists (i.e. part specifications) of the queried dataset contents.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for the deplay, I just updated the question to make it clearer. Until I actually need the values, I want to only deal with indices when querying. This question mostly applies to working on large 2D Datasets (lists of assns), and stems from my being used to workflows in python pandas DataFrames.

Comment: does `PositionIndex[d] /@ cases` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr Perhaps, how efficient is PositionIndex?

Comment: If it is an option, you might consider adding a row index to each row as a preprocessing step.

Comment: @Shredderroy Hmm, that might be expensive or not always doable for non-2D datasets... doesn’t Dataset already have an internal notion of index in the list of associations case?

Comment: Your best bet might be to first modify your original dataset by adding an "index" field, as `d = MapIndexed[Append[#1, "index" -> #2] &, d]`. This lets you do normal `Select` querying, and the index field just "comes along for the ride". However, I realize this isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: (`MapIndexed` also allows you to specify the level on which it's applied (including for nested associations) as an optional last argument, which would let you work with non-2D datasets!)

Comment: @user5601 I don't believe `Dataset` maintains any internal row indices. In your case, preprocessing would be the "correct" solution, since you always need to extract the position. You might try putting creating `Dataset` from the `Association` `<|1 -> association-for-row-1-of-d, 2 -> association-for-row-2-of-d, ...|>`. In any case, the problem you are describing seems to require a preprocessing step as a solution. Remember, even database indexes are a meta layer over the table.